# Convert Minutes and Hours to it's correspondant number

Tags: php, datetime

Sorry , I can't find good title for it.

I want to convert minutes and hours to a number.
Ex. :-

```
$hours = "3";
$minutes = "30";
```

It should show `3.5`.
If I write `4` hours and `15` minutes then it shows `4.25`.

I want to convert like this.

Comment: May I know Hours and minutes are input? $mins = $mins/60;

Comment: This is fairly simple mathematics

Comment: @MathsRkBala. Sorry, It's a input.

Comment: @chris85.sorry It should show.

Comment: @chris85. Is it feasible for every timezone `$converted_minutes = ($minutes/60)*100;` ?

Comment: `$converted_minutes = (($hours * 60) + $minutes) / 60;` You might like to do some rounding on the result

Comment: @chris85 But if I want to convert `3` hours and `30` minutes to `3.5` then multiply by 100 is necessary. I'm updating my question. please check.

Comment: @RiggsFolly. oh yeah It's working thank you :)

Comment: @chris85 You could, but I thought I would keep it simple, afterall the OP had to ask this question ;)

Comment: I just want to confirm that is it feasible for every timezone and all datetime format but Now I'm clear that it's working. Thank you so much every one for your precious time :)

Comment: @chris85. Yeah it was a typo. Ohk great thank you for your efforts please add your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just divide the minutes by there maximum value (60) and then add that to your hours to get the full value.

```
$hours = "3";
$minutes = "30";
echo $hours + ($minutes / 60);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/819401

Also note the `+` here is adding, not concatenating. If you concatenate you get an extra decimal place appended to the hours value because the decimal is `0.fractionvalue`.

Answer (score -2):

```
$convertedTime = (($hours * 60) + $minutes) / 60;
```

You will need to add some rounding or cutting off decimal digits

Comment: Ummm did you come up with this all on your own?